# Running generated edmx.sqlce file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I started off from an existing database and added some associations in the edmx designer. This seemed to cause trouble, so I decided to generate the database from the model I had created in the designer. All this did is create a .edmx.sqlce file that I can not get to run and make all my queries reference non-existant columns. ("[Name]_ID" for all my associations)

Is there a way to execute this file on my existing database in Visual Studio at all? My current .sdf database file is accessible in the Server Explorer under Data Connections at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my SQL Server Toolbox addin to execute the script, you may need to add some GO lines, see my blog post here http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/02/fixing-entity-framework-designer.html